# Voltage Divider Circuit - Not Working?

Tags: voltage, led, voltage-divider

I am an EE student. I've been making this LED sign for my church. I am using those generic LED light strips that everyone hangs in their room. When testing the circuit in Multisim Live, everything looked fine. But when I built the circuit and soldered it, something went wrong. The resistors are reading (with a DMM) completely wrong. I know they are the right values though. I'm guessing this is a dumb error of all the resistors being in a parallel setup, but, why did it test right in Multisim? Additionally, how would I fix this?

Thanks, Noah

[image: Schematic]

[image: Actual (soldered) Circuit]

Comment: what voltages were you expecting? ... what voltages did you measure? ... there are no LEDs in your schematic

Comment: LEDs are current driven, not voltage.  You need to deliver the correct current, not a specific voltage.  Consider how much current you are going to get through those resistors, then look at how much current the LEDs require.  The normal way to driver LEDs is with a series resistor, not a voltage divider.

Comment: What is the purpose of the resistors? Aren't the LED strips are directly powered with 12V? Generally one would not use a resistor divider in a power supply circuit for the reason that it does not work for high power loads.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the resistors after you have soldered them into the circuit? That probably will not work.

Comment: Your simulation gives different results because you forgot to put the LEDs into it.  I think if you did you would find that your circuit doesn't light up the LEDs because the resistors are huge and because that isn't an appropriate circuit to drive LEDs.  Why do you think you need that circuit in the first place?  LED strips can be run directly off of a power supply, not circuit needed.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. I always forget that LEDs are current-driven, not voltage-driven. The reason I have this resistor-divider network is because i want two specific colors, Purple and Pink. I tested the voltages (when using the remote that turns it purple and pink (and any color you want) and the voltages in the schematic are the ones that I got from that experiment, so I assumed if I made 6 voltage dividers, I would get those colors I want. I cant just use the remote, because i want half to be purple, and half to be pink.

Comment: I think what I'll do instead is put in 6 POTs, one in place of each voltage divider; that way I can adjust the current in each R, G, and B branch.

Comment: Someone let me know if there is a problem with this (^) before I do it please!